# More elegant way to write if else in python

Tags: python, coding-style

For example if I have the code:

```
class Example ():

    def a(self):
        return 'Buy'

    def b(self):
        if (self.a() == 'Buy'):
            return 'BUY SET'
        elif (self.a() == 'Sell'):
            return 'SELL SET''

o = Example()
value = o.b()   
print value
```

Is there a more elegant/pythonic way I could write function b(self) ?

Comment: Remove the unneeded parens and store `result = self.a()` before doing the comparisons (personal preference). Having an else clause might be useful too.

Comment: I think, as a start, the "more elegant/pythonic" thing to do would be to use meaningful names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, get rid of the unnecessary parentheses; they just make the structure of your code harder to follow:

```
def b(self):
    if self.a() == 'Buy':
        return 'BUY SET'
    elif self.a() == 'Sell':
        return 'SELL SET''
```

Then remove that stray `'` that causes it to raise a `SyntaxError`:

```
def b(self):
    if self.a() == 'Buy':
        return 'BUY SET'
    elif self.a() == 'Sell':
        return 'SELL SET'
```

Next, don't call `self.a()` twice. While it's harmless here, in real code there's a very good chance it will have side effects—or at least take long enough that you're wasting time:

```
def b(self):
    order = self.a()
    if order == 'Buy':
        return 'BUY SET'
    elif order == 'Sell':
        return 'SELL SET'
```

Next, if `a` returns anything but `'Buy'` or `'Sell'`, you're going to return `None`. Is that really what you want? How you fix this depends on what you actually want. For example, you might want:

```
def b(self):
    order = self.a()
    if order == 'Buy':
        return 'BUY SET'
    elif order == 'Sell':
        return 'SELL SET'
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unexpected order type '{}'".format(order))
```

Or maybe:

```
def b(self):
    order = self.a()
    if order == 'Buy':
        return 'BUY SET'
    else: # We know there's nothing else it could be
        return 'SELL SET'
```

If you have more than two possibilities, it might be worth putting things into a `dict` instead of using an `if`/`elif` chain, or writing dynamic code. Examples:

```
def b(self):
    return {'Buy': 'BUY SET', 'Sell': 'SELL SET', 'Trade': 'TRADE SET',
            'Barter': 'BARTER SET', 'Steal': 'STEAL SET'}[self.a()]

def b(self):
    return '{} SET'.format(order.upper())
```

Note that these make different choices for the previous question. The `dict` version will raise a `KeyError` for an unknown value; the `format` version will just treat anything as valid.

Also, if you use a `dict`, you probably want to move it outside of the `b` function—e.g., make it a class attribute (which also encourages you to give it a nice name).

However, for only two choices, I think what you have is much clearer.

Finally, it's not very pythonic to give functions meaningless one-letter names; it would be better to do something like this:

```
def get_formatted_order(self):
    order = self.calculate_order()
    if order == 'Buy':
        return 'BUY SET'
    elif order == 'Sell':
        return 'SELL SET''
```

Comment: But if `a` can only return `'Buy'` or `'Sell'`, then you'd be better off with an `if-else` clause rather than an `if-elif` clause.

Comment: @Volatility: The paragraph starting with "Next, if `a` returns…" is intended to deal with that issue. But maybe it should be more explicit? I'll try rewriting it; thanks.

Comment: Geeze. Get off the lecture podium already ^^ (A nice well-rounded answer.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary:

```
def b(self):
    return {'Buy': "BUY SET", 'Sell': "SELL SET"}.get(self.a())
```

Or written more clearly:

```
def b(self):
    d = {"Buy": "BUY SET",
        "Sell": "SELL SET"}
    return d.get(self.a())
```

Comment: @Marcin that's why I used `get` - defaults to `None`

Comment: This is short and looks alright, but you are needless initiating a dictionary.

Comment: @ajon and what exactly would be the problem with that? There's no indication that a small time and space overhead would be a problem for OP, he's just asking for more elegant code.

Comment: I agree with @pst, but this is still a good demonstration of how you _would_ do it if you had, say, 20 different choices instead of 2.

Comment: @pst yeah, it's not that big of an optimization for just two choices, but everything else I could recommend to OP would have been trivial.

Comment: I would always use a dictionary for stuff like this - it makes it infinitely easier to add items later, and makes it easier to allow use of that mapping in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Although abarnet's answer is definitely the most conclusive, for the given code, this would also work:

```
def b(self):
    return self.a().upper() + " SET"
```

But that's making a lot of assumptions that aren't very generalizable.

Comment: This is equivalent to one of the options in my answer, except that I used `format` instead of concatenation. Pulling it out into a separate answer does help to highlight it as a possibility, but I'm not sure it deserves to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just cache it?

```
def b(self):
    a = self.a()

    if a == 'Buy':
        return 'BUY SET'
    elif a == 'Sell':
        return 'SELL SET''
```

I'd give your variables legible names as well. `a` and `b` aren't descriptive at all.

Answer (score 1):

After all cool recomendations that [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14269483/438069) you can try one more trick for shortening your code.

```
def get_formatted_order(self):
    order = self.calculate_order()        
    return 'BUY SET' if order == 'Buy' else 'SELL SET'
```

This is the pythonic form of ternary operator. If order evaluates to 'Buy' function will return 'BUY SET'. In opposite case it will return 'SELL  SET'